# /= operation in C++

Tags: c++, operation

As I understand this code returns the number of digits entered in the function but I don't understand this operation:
    `(number /= 10) != 0` at all..I understand that this line
    `number /= 10`
equal to `number = number / 10` but why not but why in this function they don't write `number / 10 != 0`? and what are the differences?

```
std::size_t numDigits(int number) // function definition.
{                                 // (This function returns
std::size_t digitsSoFar = 1;      // the number of digits
                                  // in its parameter.)
while ((number /= 10) != 0) ++digitsSoFar;
return digitsSoFar;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself: If the loop condition is `number / 10 != 0`, when would the loop stop?

Comment: The `/=` operator modifies the variable on the left-hand side. The `/` operator does not modify the variable.  The loop is meant to end when the `number` variable becomes 0, which won't happen when using `/` instead of `/=`.

Comment: Just pondering: I wonder which is faster... this or `std::ceil(std::log10(number))`... division is probably more expensive then logarithm

Comment: @JHB I'd think it'd depend on the size of the number. If you pass a one digit number, for example, that `while` would basically act as an `if`. There's probably some point when your method becomes faster...

Comment: @scohe001 true, but that's about the only exception...

Comment: I think whether or not that's the exception depends on the use case ;) for all we know, they could be passing numbers between 1-999 into this function, so a loop would be faster. Or maybe all of their values are 8+ digits so yours would be. It all depends...it's a good question to ask though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(number /= 10) != 0
```

This actually has 3 steps. It...

1. Calculates `number / 10`
2. Assigns that value to `number`
3. Checks if that value is not equal to `0`

So in answer to your question, "why in this function they don't write `number / 10 != 0`," let's walk through what that does:

1. Calculates `number / 10`
2. Checks if that value is not equal to `0`

Can you see the difference between the two?

If you're still not sure why this matters, put an output statement in the while loop that'll show `number` and `digitsSoFar` and try to run that function both the way it's written and then with your proposed version.